# How transfer an array of integers from C to Matlab

Tags: c, arrays, matlab, transfer

Is there a somewhat easy way to transfer an array of integers from a C program to matlab? I have found several guides online on how to do it between C++ and Matlab, but not for C to Matlab.

I have several arrays of 1180 floats that I produce with a program written in C. Now I want to visualize this data in Matlab. I could have the C program export the Matlab code necessary to create the arrays hard-coded, but this seems unnecesarily devious.

I could just use the C++ method and compile my C program with a C++ compiler but at this point I am just curious if it can also be done in C.

Matlab can import .mat files, but these files seem to be encrypted or in binary format.

Please don't give suggestions on how to visualize the data in C, I **have** to do it in Matlab. I have a piece of code in Matlab that is returning weird results and I wrote the equivalent code in C, now I want to see if there is a difference in results. This way I can debug my Matlab code, since the end result has to be handed in in Matlab code.

My C code so far. Also I made a mistake in my initial upload, I want to transfer an array of integers.

```
FILE *f = fopen("Ps.bin", "wb");
for(int n = 1; n < N + 1; n++)
{
    converter.asInt = Ps[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        fwrite(&converter.asBytes[i], sizeof(char), 1, f);
    }
}
fclose(f);
```

This is what I tried in matlab, but none of it gives the proper result. In all cases matlab makes an array of doubles, which I definately don't want. It just generates an array with values that are one of these three: 0, 0.0000 and 4.925.

```
Ps = fread(fopen('Ps.bin'))
Ps = fread(fopen('Ps.bin'), 1180)
Ps = fread(fopen('Ps.bin'), 1180, 'uint32')
Ps = fread(fopen('Ps.bin'), 1180, '2 * uint16')
```

Comment: Why not simply write the floats to a binary, text, or whatever file in C and import that into MATLAB?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? Only thing that seems to be missing is that you need to write file in a format that Matlab can understand, and it seems that your C++ guides already explain this.

Comment: Yea but the C++ methods use C++ libraries I cannot use in C. And right now I'm just curious if there are any trivial ways of doing it in C.

Comment: You could [read a 1 x N matrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readmatrix.html) (be sure in C to print the floats with maximum precision in this case, comma separated for instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a binary file in C (using `fwrite`, look [here](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-file-input-output)). From matlab, you can read it using the procedure [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) (`fread`function)

Comment: I made some changes in the initial post. I can't get it to work for some reason. The C part works fine but matlab completely breaks everything.

Comment: It does work however when I convert everything to float on the C program's side. Somehow matlab seems to be unable to interpret binary files that contain integers, or maybe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: is there a reason why you use this way of saving your binary file? Why not just save it using ```fwrite(Ps, sizeof(int), 1180, f);``` then in Matlab, use ```fread(fopen('Ps.bin'), 1180, 'int')```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm